# Returning content directly from memcache - Django / HTTP Server

Tags: django, apache, http, memcached

I've built a web application with **Django**, I'm using **Memcached** in order to cache data.

A few views cache the whole HttpResponse objects, therefore there might be a better alternative for returning the Memcached data other than going through Django.

**What could be faster alternatives for returning Memcached data on HTTP Requests ?**

---

I'm trying to make the operation as **fast** and **lightweight** as possible.

Help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for some sort of proxying server which can take the cached page and serve it without going through Django at all. You might take a look at [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a faster way to "cache/retrieve a whole Python object" (given that `memcached` stores *strings*) than `cPickle`'s `loads` and `dumps` methods with a second argument of `-1` (which tells `cPickle` to use the fastest, tightest algorithm available).

That's if you're using memcached directly; if you're using it as the backend of Django's own cache system, you can use it [per-view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache), etc, and Django will handle the serialization (and more) on your behalf.

Comment: @Alex: thanks for this. I was thinking more about caching the text that is being requested rather than a Pickled HttpResponse object. So that any application could plug in and return the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use nginx as a proxy server in front of Apache, you can use its memcached module to serve cached HTML output directly from memcached. This data can be created and put into memcached by Django. I do think that the nginx memcached module only supports one memcached server instance though. Here are a couple of links that show the principles:

http://weichhold.com/2008/09/12/django-nginx-memcached-the-dynamic-trio/

http://bretthoerner.com/blog/2008/oct/27/using-nginx-memcached-module-django/